# References to commits on deleted branches

Tags: git, github

I have a GitHub issue that references commits on a deleted branch and I'm unsure if this is to be expected.

This is what I've done so far:

1. Branched 'feature/7' from 'dev'
2. Made two commits to this branch with each commit referencing issue #7
3. After each commit I pushed to remote
4. Squashed the two commits on 'feature/7' and changed the commit
   message to reference issue #7
5. Pushed to remote. It stated I needed to force a push which I did. At this point issue #7 has a reference to the two commits and the squashed commit.
6. Merged 'feature/7' into 'dev'
7. Deleted the 'feature/7' branch on local and remote.

The references to the two commits on 'feature/7' are still accessible in the GitHub issue even though the branch has been deleted.

Is this correct? And, is this process the correct way to go about using feature branches?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is expected. By default, GitHub doesn't garbage-collect old objects, so they will continue to exist so that they can be referenced, just like you're seeing now. As long as the object existed in the repository originally, it is probably still accessible and any behaviors caused by it (like a link to an issue) are still present.

And yes, this is a fine workflow to use for feature branches. Squashing changes into a single commit is a common workflow, and if the change is logically only one commit, it's even the preferred workflow. If your change involves logically separate changes (such as a refactor and a new feature), you can split them into separate commits as Git upstream does.

Comment: Thanks for your help bk2204.